# Using gitlab-ci to deploy a file using scp fails only when triggered by a tag

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys

When using gitlab-ci to deploy a file to a server using scp, the scp command fails only when the pipeline job is triggered from a tag

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/ubuntu-1804-qt5-builder:master

stages:
  - debian-package
  - deploy

variables:
  RELEASE_NAME: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.${CI_PIPELINE_ID}

before_script:
  ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

  ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  ## without extra base64 encoding.
  ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null

  ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts


debian-package:
  stage: debian-package
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y -f debhelper
  script:
    - 'export DEB_PACKAGE=${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_$(echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | sed "s/master/0.0/g")-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}_all.deb'
    - 'echo BUILDING: ${DEB_PACKAGE}'
    - ./prepdebian.sh ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} "$(echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | sed 's/master/0.0/g')" "${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" "${GITLAB_USER_NAME} <${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}>" "${CI_COMMIT_SHA}"
    - dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b
    - cp ../${DEB_PACKAGE} .
  artifacts:
    name: ${RELEASE_NAME}
    paths: 
      - ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_$(echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | sed 's/master/0.0/g')-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}_all.deb

deploy-staging:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies: 
    - debian-package
  script:
    - 'export DEB_PACKAGE=${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_$(echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | sed "s/master/0.0/g")-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}_all.deb'
    - 'echo DEPLOYING TO STAGING: ${DEB_PACKAGE}'
    - scp -vvv ${DEB_PACKAGE} user@server.com:incomming/debs/
  only:
    - tags
```

I have set the scp command to provide verbose output (-vvv)
The output from scp shows

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host server.com, user user, command scp -v -t incomming/debs/
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "server.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server.com [11.22.33.44] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to server.com:22 as 'user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ooGb0IBrr6wGPwJo23g+eMW9S6lkIOQ5lx0XL4PReeg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

If you replace the pipeline job trigger from

```
  only:
    - tags
```

to

```
  except:
    - tags
```

Then the scp command succeeds

This does not make any sense, could some one shed some light on why the deployment fails only when using `only: tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I have finally resolved the issue.

I set the variable  **CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"**. This allowed a lot more information about the environment to be output. When doing this I noticed that the **SSH_PRIVATE_KEY** was being set; however, the **SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS** was not. This was only the case if the following was used.

```
  only:
    - tags
```

The variables **SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS** and **SSH_PRIVATE_KEY** where CI variables.

The variable **SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS** was mistakenly set to be protected.
The strange thing which I still do not understand, event though the variable was set as protected , the environment was set to *All environments (*)*